# GCM message sent from node-gcm server but not received

Tags: android, node.js, google-cloud-messaging

this is the result in node-gcm server

```
**

{ multicast_id: 5309930915296650000,
  success: 1,
  failure: 0,
  canonical_ids: 0,
  results: [ { message_id: '0:1410197314824005%31e4cc17f9fd7ecd' } ] }
```

**

and my server code in which i retrieve reg_ids from my mongoDb and store them in a string array and pass it to the send method

```
exports.create = function ( req, res ){
  new Comment({
   // username : req.body.username,
    content : req.body.comment,
    created : Date.now()
  }).save( function( err, comment, count ){
    res.redirect( '/' );
  });

reg_ids=[];

User.find({},'gcm_id',function(err,res)
  {


  for(i=0;i<res.length;i++)
  { 
  reg_ids.push(res[i].gcm_id);

  console.log(i+'th entry is '+res[i].gcm_id+'\n');

  }
// reg_ids=res.toArray();


var message = new gcm.Message();
message.delay_while_idle = 1;
message.addDataWithKeyValue('message',req.body.comment);


sender.send(message, reg_ids, 4, function (err, result) {
    console.log(result);




});






});

};
```

everything in the server seems fine

and my receiver
here i placed a Log.D to check if receiver is triggered
but it was not

```
    package com.javapapers.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;
import android.util.Log;

public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        Log.d("receiver", "received");
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GCMNotificationIntentService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

and finally my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.javapapers.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.javapapers.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.javapapers.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 

        >

        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.javapapers.android.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.GCM_RECEIVED_ACTION"/>

                <category android:name="com.javapapers.android" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".GCMNotificationIntentService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

i've been struck with this from a long time
I would be thankful if someone could help

Comment: This looks like previously [reported](https://github.com/ToothlessGear/node-gcm/issues/70) [issues](https://github.com/ToothlessGear/node-gcm/issues/66), but they haven't been reproduced for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the message key and value in order for the message to send. 
Like so:

```
message.addData('message', 'push notification worked');
```